# Videos gone from right-click menu

Tags: files, directory

Videos used to be an option when I right-click on the files icon on my launcher.  Now it's gone even though that directory still exists.  Why did it go away and how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it disappeared, but I got it back by adding it to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.